# How to add a favicon.ico to a PHP website?

Tags: web-applications, favicon

All I want to do is add a favicon.ico to my PHP website. Is there a simple PHP way of doing this or can it only be done with an HTML reference page?

Maybe using some jQuery/Ajax/JavaScript?

Comment: you already have Kovo's answer that should be what you need, I just want to point that you are considering PHP and HTML two different things that don't have anything to do with each other.. in most cases (and yours) PHP is a language used to output HTML.. so the solution could be a mixture of both: send from php the url to the image that is placed in your html (in the head section)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

By default, most browsers will try to resolve the favicon.ico, even if you do not mention it in the HTML of the website (just make sure the file is in the root of the website directory). However, for compatibility, you should add the html code for it in the  section of your web page.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
```

Comment: There's no specific PHP way to do it.  Just have your PHP print out your <link> tag or put the favicon in the root of your webserver.  Standards: http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon

Comment: This worked perfectly thanks! Just added the <link> tag into the head and slapped an echo on front of it.